# Does this schema achieve conditional required properties?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Does my schema rules achieve my desired results? Essentially, the properties `email` and `phone` are required IF `message` equals `success` otherwise they can be absent.

```
{
    "message": "success", // REQUIRED can be "success", "user does not exist"
    "email": "foo@bar.com", // CONDITIONALLY REQUIRED if message="success" otherwise can be null or ""
    "phone": "0210001000", // CONDITIONALLY REQUIRED if message="success" otherwise can be null or ""
}
```

Is this schema correct in achieving my above needs?

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "message": { "const": "success" }
    },
    "required": ["email", "phone"]
  },
  "else": { 
    "required": ["message"] 
  },
  "properties": {
    "message": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "email"
    },
    "phone": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, although I'd probably make `message` required at the root level. Have you... tried it?

Comment: There's no `then` keyword.  The way `if`/`then`/`else` works is: if the `if` schema passes, then the `then` schema must also pass, else the `else` schema must pass.  If either the `then` or `else` keywords are missing, they are assumed to be `true`, which passes everything.  So I would think that the `required: [email, phone]` would need to move into a `then` keyword.